# Showing different images depending on user role

Tags: comments, user-roles

in my comments I wanna show different avatars depending on the user role that the person has, that was giving upto the comment (not the role of the logged in user).

I tried like it follows inside comments loop:

```
   <?php
   $commentator_id = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;
   $commentator_info = get_userdata($commentator_id);
   $capabilities = $user_info->wp_capabilities;
   if (array_key_exists('editor', $capabilities)) {
      // echo markup here
   }
?>
```

But it doesn't function. Does anybody know why ?

Answer (score 0):

What's the variable `$user_info` in you code? Probably you mean `$commentator_info`? If yes, this is certainly the error. You are trying to extract `wp_capabilities` (?) from a non-initialized variable (`$user_info`).

Try this:

```
    <?php
   $comment_id = get_comment_ID();
   $comment_data = get_comment($comment_id);
   $commentator_id = $comment_data->user_id;
   $commentator_info = get_userdata($commentator_id); // get_userdata, with the user ID specified, returns a WP_User object.

   if ( user_can($commentator_info, 'editor') ) {  // user_can accept the user ID or the whole user object ($commentator_info).
      // echo markup here
   }
```

Changes: added `$comment_id` and `$comment_data` variables (now it's more readable), deleted `$capabilities` (you don't need to store the capabilities in a variable, you can check them directly passing the whole user object (or the user ID) and the capability you want to verify to `user_can()`. Added `user_can()` and removed the array-key check.

Comment: Sorry it only checks the logged in user and n ot the user, that was posting the comment...What to do ?

Comment: Sorry, so you want to operate on user not-logged in? A not-logged user cannot have a capability such as "editor"; they are all visitors/guests. What's the point?

Comment: No, I want, that for a user that is a subscriber and was writing a comment, another image near his comment is shown as for an user that was writing a comment and is an editor. The query has to be whitch role has the user, of this the comment ist !